# GA4 custom dimensions available in reports but always showing not set in explore

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm using GA4 and I have added some custom dimensions.  I see these reflected properly (well, I think properly) in GTM and in the real-time debug view within google analytics.

Here's what I see in GTM when I click "ABOUT" in the main menu and the tag fires:
[image]

Here's what I see in GA4 debug view for the same event:
[image]

Here's what I see in GA4 under Engagement > Events:
[image]

Note that my parameter is clearly coming through and the parameter values are coming through with good counts.  However, this data is only for the last 30 minutes.  I want to do more exploration on my main menu clicks over longer periods of time, so I setup a super simple exploration.  However, I don't see the parameter values or counts in exploration.  I only see "not set".

[image]

I expected to see in the rows a list of parameter values (the same ones shown under engagement > events) with their relative event counts.  I do not see them or any sort of error message.  I don't see a way to drill down further or any of the parameter values available anywhere.

I do not know how to troubleshoot this.  I don't understand how it works in one area and not another.  I don't see an error message that lets me dig deeper.  All the troubleshooting guides I can find help troubleshoot data not coming through at all and focus on misnamed variables or not enough time passing for the data to be calculated, but those don't seem to be helpful.  I'm actually getting the data and it has been collecting for months.  Maybe I'm just not understanding how the explore fields work?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot on how you set the custom event parameter in the `Custom definitions`?

Comment: Custom event parameter screenshot here: [https://imgur.com/a/RohUV05](https://imgur.com/a/RohUV05)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check here.

From the screenshot you provide in comment.

You set the `link_text`. But it should be `menu_item_clicked`

Because you already sent it with the event.

---

The blue part here is the `name` of the event parameter you want to show in UI or using in Data API as a report.

The red part here is the `name` of the event parameter you sent from GTM or `gtag`

So if you set the blue part as `menu_item_clicked` but the red part does not.

You will get `(not set)` in explorer. You can try to modify here and wait for one or two days.

[image]

Comment: I have made this change.  I will wait the required 24-48 hour time to see if this resolves the issue.  I'm still baffled at why it would appear in the 30 minute chart, but not in other places.

Comment: Oh, wait, because the 30 minute chart let me select the parameter name and displayed the associated values and the change I just made was a dimension name that has a subsequent parameter name discrepancy.  I think I see why it worked in one place and not the other.  Let's see if this resolves after the required time passes.

Comment: @ssorj did you manage to resolve this? We're experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @DanielHunt Yes. It was resolved after the time passed.  It was a naming discrepancy.